# jest-mongodb error: TypeError: Class extends value undefined is not a constructor or null

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, jestjs

I'm trying to run tests with `jest` on a basic `mongodb` set-up with `express`. following the instructions in the [jestjs.io documentation](https://jestjs.io/docs/mongodb). When I run may `package.json` script: `"test": "jest"` I get the following error:

```
    TypeError: Class extends value undefined is not a constructor or null

      at Object.<anonymous> (node_modules/@shelf/jest-mongodb/environment.js:20:49)
```

The line in `environment.js` referenced above is:

```js
module.exports = class MongoEnvironment extends TestEnvironment {
```

So the `TestEnvironment`class is undefined. Judging from other stack discussions it looks like there's some circular reference issue. Possibly to be solved by changing the order of how the modules are run, but I don't know how to do this?

I've tried changing my version of node, and I've also tried deleting my node_modules and reinstalling. When I run `yarn check` it tells me all my packages are in sync.

`package.json`:

```json
...
  "dependencies": {
    "dotenv": "^16.0.1",
    "express": "^4.18.1",
    "mongodb": "^4.6.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.18.2",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.18.2",
    "@babel/preset-typescript": "^7.17.12",
    "@shelf/jest-mongodb": "^3.0.0",
    "@types/express": "^4.17.13",
    "@types/jest": "^27.5.1",
    "@types/mongodb": "^4.0.7",
    "@types/node": "^17.0.36",
    "jest": "^28.1.0",
    "jest-environment-node": "^27.0.0",
    "ts-jest": "^28.0.3",
    "ts-node-dev": "^2.0.0",
    "typescript": "^4.7.2"
  },
...
```

Answer (score 1):

I got rid of this error by updating:

`"jest-environment-node": "^27.0.0",`

to

`"jest-environment-node": "^28.1.0",`

Answer (score 1):

I was able to solve it from:

```
const NodeEnvironment = require('jest-environment-node')
```

to:

```
const NodeEnvironment = require('jest-environment-node').default
```